# Installing specific dotnet version in azure

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm having an issue with a netcoreapp project that's running 2.2. In Microsoft Azure the 2 supported versions are 2.1 and 3.1, both will require some serious migrating. Is it possible to install 2.2 on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to deploy a self-contained application. You can do so by running

```
dotnet publish -r <RID> --self-contained
```

In this way you will cut loose the depedency on the supported runtimes from Azure side.

There is of course the downside (as always) that your applications would be bigger by roughly 100Mb

Comment: Thank you! BTW is there a way to enable the same thing with Github Actions integration. I've set it up from the deployment center.

Comment: I tried it with the default configuration file and it throws an error, so I will have to dig in more in order to use this command with the github actions config.